# How to have multiple processes in zsh or bash appending to the same file concurrently?

Tags: bash, shell, concurrency, zsh

I am running some tests from shell (currently zsh but could be bash as well) concurrently that will output the results by appending to the same file (results.txt).

Each result will be a few lines and some hundred bytes long (not longer than 1000).

I want to be able to read the output of each test in whole in the results file, without any interleaving from any test that might have finished at the same time.

I see a couple of obvious options from a theoretical point of view:

1. Atomic write(append)
2. Use a mutex to acquire the results file

The problem is that I have no idea whether how to do any of the 2 in a shell.
More specifically, I don't know if appends are atomic by nature and I don't know how to use a mutex in a shell context.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Polling is not good , but a solution to your problem can be to have the parent bash script execute the sub scripts/commands in the background. Have the sub scripts/commands write to their own files. The parent script should keep a note of the pid each time it executes the test. Once all the tests have been executed ,stArt a loop to check the pids existence , once all pids have gone from the terminal is when the tests have completed. When you reach this stage , start collecting the data from each file sequentially onto the combined new file

Comment: If the file is on the same file system as the two process (i.e. not on a network share), you could use `flock` to synchronize them.

Comment: there is 2 way to approach , 1 - using `> result.txt` in your **shell script** and redirect all the result in result.txt and then using`>> result.txt`  for your second test to append to result.txt                                                       Or you can create 2 result file for each of your tests and the using [join command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-command-linux/) join those two files into onefile

Comment: @user1934428 I found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274499/134886 but I don't understand the flock syntax. Can you help explain what is the meaning of 200 for example?

Comment: Did you read the flock man-page? It says: _The third form uses an open file by its file descriptor **number**_.